# Clamping Negative Logarithm of the probability to a positive value in a information retrieval environment(Language Modelling)

Tags: algorithm, math, information-retrieval, logarithm

If we take logarithms of probability the value returned is negative.Value is used  in a matcher of information retrieval library which rejects the negative value hence i need to clamp the negative value to a positive value,so that matcher doesn't reject the document.

One approach could be add a random number say K to the probability

i.e return max(log( prob. + K) where K is a large constant or return max(log(K.Prob),0) where K is a large constant

Is there any better approach to clamp the negative log value to positive? which of these would be a better approach to follow?

In case we select any of the above approach, i feel very dizzy about how to select an appropriate K. I would be glad if someone can suggest how to select an appropriate large K ?

P.S it is important to use logarithm values as we are trying to implement model where we need to multiply probability but due to in-feasibility of architecture to support that we are summing the log of probability which is product of probability,hence using log value is important (taking antilog is not a workable approach) here

Comment: Could you simple take the negative of the logarithm? Since you are dealing with probabilities (i.e. values <= 1), the logarithm is _always_ negative, so negating it will _always_ make it positive. The only downside I can think of is that, as a result, _large_ values will indicate low probabilities, _small_ values will indicate high probabilities, so the meaning of your log-probabilities is reversed. But is that a problem?

Comment: since these weights are used to ranks the document in rank list,hence document with low probability will be ranked higher and possible good documents will be rejected by matcher otherwise reversing rank-list could have been a workable approach...
hence negating the vallues wont be desirable solution

Comment: I think @jogojapan has the right idea here, that should be the place to start...there is no value of `K` that is guaranteed to give you a positive number, since `log(x) -> -inf` as `x -> 0`. Unless of course you can be sure of the range of your probabilities...

Comment: @kaveman negating value will work fine as far as getting value to positive is concern,but this would reject the good documents due to lower score.
So loosing good document due to lower probability having larger value and higher probability having lower value wont work out in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use log(1 + p). This will offset your range from (-inf, 0] -> [0, log(2)]. This I think will solve your problem.

The most used way in general is to take negative of log as suggested by others. You can alternatively use 1/(1-log(p)) as well but this will not be helpful in your case.

So log(1 + p) seems to be the best solution.

Comment: answer is correct, i tried it out but it basically creates problem in framework of search engine and unfair advantage to some documents.